# Advanced installer - mandatory prerequisite was not correctly installed

Tags: advanced-installer

Tried to install some feature-based prerequisites but it can't installed.
In logs looks like driver installation error 4153.

> CustomAction AI_VerifyPrereq returned actual error code 1603

And inside installation it looks like

[image]

But if I running this driver installation outside advanced installer it's gone good and return exit code 0.
Don't know what wrong with this.
Please, ask any additional information if you need.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this message appears when the install conditions associated with prerequisites are not valid. In order for a prerequisite to successfully be reported as installed a valid install condition is needed that will not be met if the prerequisite is not installed and will be met if the prerequisite is installed.

The [install conditions](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/prerequisites-install-conditions.html) for prerequisites are evaluated at two specific moments:

- At the beginning of the package installation process. If the condition is met then the prerequisite will not be installed because it is already present on the target machine. If the condition is not met the prerequisite will be scheduled for installation.
- After the installation of prerequisites. Once the prerequisites are installed the associated conditions will be re-evaluated. If the conditions are met then the prerequisites were successfully installed. If the conditions are not met then the installation of the prerequisites failed and the message you got is displayed.